# Okta login redirection does not update authState

Tags: reactjs, okta

Trying to integrate Okta with ReactJs web. Web app successfully route user to Okta login page, user managed to login successful too. Upon login successful, Okta redirected back to ReactJs web without `authState` update (authState is `NULL` while trying to read).

With my implemented code, im aways getting redirected back to `Home.js` with the `Loading...` text. What seems to be missing here?

###### Sample code impelmentation as below

App.js

```
const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth({
    issuer: 'https://{{ourDomain}}.com/oauth2/default',
    clientId: '{{ourValue}}',
    redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/login/callback',
    scopes: ["openid", "profile", "email"],
    pkce: true,
  });

<Security oktaAuth={oktaAuth} restoreOriginalUri={restoreOriginalUri}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login/callback" component={LoginCallback} />
          <Route path="/" component={Home} />
          <SecureRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        </Switch>
      </Security>
```

Home.js

```
const { oktaAuth, authState } = useOktaAuth();
const login = async () => await oktaAuth.signInWithRedirect();
const logout = async () => oktaAuth.signOut();

const renderLogin = () => {
        if(!authState) {
          return <div>Loading...</div>;
        }
    
        if(!authState.isAuthenticated) {
            return (
            <div>
                <p>Not Logged in yet</p>
                <button onClick={login}>Login</button>
            </div>
            );
        }
    
        return (
            <div style={{backgroundColor:'blue'}}>
                <p>Logged in!</p>
                <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
            </div>
        );
    }    

    return (
        <div style={{height:'100%',justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center',display:'flex'}}>
            {renderLogin()}
        </div>
    );
```

FYI

```
"@okta/okta-auth-js": "^7.2.0",
"@okta/okta-react": "^6.7.0",
```

##### Update:

Here's what i'm seeing with `oktaAuth` after redirected back from Okta Hosted Login.

[image]

#### Issue resolved:

Root cause identified, it was due to the use of different router from `react-router-dom`

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom"; --- use this
// import { HashRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom"; --- this give issue, due to the extra # return in url
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue resolved:

Root cause identified, it was due to the use of different router from `react-router-dom`

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom"; --- use this
// import { HashRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom"; --- this give issue, due to the extra # in url
```

Also I have added 1 extra key:value while initializing OktaAuth. Previously it was not part of my declaration.

```
const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth({
    clientId: CLIENT_ID,
    issuer: ISSUER,
    redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI,
    scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'email'],
    pkce: true,
    disableHttpsCheck: OKTA_TESTING_DISABLEHTTPSCHECK,
  });
```